# Change direction of disclosure triangle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nscell

How can I change the direction of the disclosure triangle programmatically?
In Interface Builder it's possible by changing the value "Control -> Layout" from "Left to Right" or "Right to Left".

I made a diff of a NIB file. The only change was `NSCellFlags2`.

Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you’re looking for is `-[NSCell setUserInterfaceLayoutDirection:]`. You need to obtain a reference to the corresponding cell and then send it the appropriate message. For example, considering `disclosureButton` points to that disclosure button:

```
[[disclosureButton cell] setUserInterfaceLayoutDirection:NSUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft];
```