# Set right-to-left orientation for NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, macos, internationalization, right-to-left

Right-to-left (RTL) languages expect that the checkbox/radiobutton is to the right of the text in checkbox/radiobutton groups and that the text is right aligned.

When I set right-to-left language ([Testing Your Internationalized App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW2)) most of the elements in the interface are respecting this setting, but checkboxes and radiobuttons are still incorrectly aligned.

I tried to explicitly set the direction by calling `[cell setUserInterfaceLayoutDirection:NSUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft]` but that does not seem to have any effect even though it is recommended in this [mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg42804.html).

Building a "reverse column order" solution ([as recommended for NSTable here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html)) for the NSMatrix require some more work since I use a single column `NSMatrix` with `NSButtonCell`.

**Related questions:**

- [Change direction of disclosure triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574710/change-direction-of-disclosure-triangle)

What is the recommended way to adapt `checkboxes` and `radiobutton` in `NSMatrix`:es to RTL languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to manually set the "image" position and text alignment.

```
[cell setImagePosition:NSImageRight];
[cell setAlignment:NSRightTextAlignment];
```